# Need help in solving Vehicle Routing in a production environment

Tags: optimization, maps, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am working on a problem for my startup where I have to assign locations to delivery trucks based on an optimal route from a distribution center.

I am using [ortools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp/vehicle_routing) right now but I am working with gps coordinates unlike given example which is using a grid structure.

Right now I've figured out a way to calculate distance between coordinates and modified their demo python code but as far as I know there is no way to define gps coordinates as home depot and I am struggling there to get optimal routes from my home depot.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: Why are you using gps coordinates? Do you mean you're (a) using delivery locations which have their latitude and longitude coordinates captured by GPS or (b) you have live GPS updates from vehicles? If you're getting live GPS updates this is a realtime route optimisation problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, by providing a Distance callback function (cf. https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp/vehicle_routing#distance_callback) you can provide whatever you want as distance function...

Thus, you could see 2D location as an id (e.g. GPS location of your addresses)  then create a distance callback which calculate the shortest distance between two locations using road etc... (e.g. you can use the [GMap Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/))

For the depot, it's just a node like others (i.e. has a location), then you can set this node as the depot in the [RoutingModel Ctor](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L353)...

note: You should create a Distance cost matrix first then use it as a look up table to return distance in constant time during iteration cf [example in the doc](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp/tsp#dist_callback1)